# Memory leaks because of event handlers

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, memory-leaks

Currently, I have to fix an existing Silverlight application that's leaking a lot of memory. Using [Redgate's ANT profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/index2) I managed to detect possible problems. One of them is a static class that wraps around a web service, which contains two event handlers to support an asynchronous calculation.
And you've guessed it... A lot of objects assign an event to this handler but most don't release it again. As a result, those objects are linked to these static events and thus almost never released...

I need a simple fix to work around this problem. So, what possible options do I have to fix this memory leak without these changes having a lot of impact?

Making the event handlers non-static will result in a huge change, thus an undesired action...

Comment: You could try unassigning the event handlers when you no longer need them?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness: I guess it's the typical scenario where a library is provided, but you don't have the control of the callers' quality of coding. But you are right, this is actually the best solution... do a clean calling with subscription and unsubscription of the events.

Comment: Unassigning is an option but this project is a big mess... I didn't create it but they expect me to perform miracles. :-) The biggest challenge is finding the right locations where I can unassign them. With 100.000 lines of code, not counting the XAML... Blimey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Weak Event pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) (don't know if it's possible with SL). This will allow a dirtier programming model with calling your static method.

A better alternative whould be to properly subscribe / unsubscribe events (agreeing with  tomasmcguinness), but this implies you can change the calling code and/or ask the consumers to better develop.

Another solution could to use async patterns. Maybe waiting for a Callback delegate in your method call, or even better, return a Task object.

Comment: The challenge is that I can't change the static class to non-static and that there are hundreds of places where this event is assigned, yet never released. The Weak Event might solve it, though.